# Stop ie 9 using compat mode because of js injection

Tags: php, javascript, meta

Hi All Hope you can  help,

I am manipulating a cms using server side php (phpQuery Library) which is injecting some minimised js into the header of a HTML page.

My problem is that I want to add meta tags to force ie9 to use standards mode. However when I inject the meta tags with php, the javascript injected after is forcing my meta tags downs and setting ie9 into compat mode.

I have have no control of the injection javascript, but can add my own scripts if this would work.

On looking at view source and inspect element when debugging I can see the js loaded on the page is forcing the meta tags down.

Could I use my own js to get them back up? I was under impression that meta tags need to be set before page load ie server.

Comment: What are the meta tags you are adding and what is the header code.. Its hard to see whats is wrong with no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a webpage that is displayed in standards mode when viewed with Internet Explorer, use the HTML5 document type directive, as shown in the following code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Enabling Standards Support</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
     Because this webpage uses the HTML5 document 
     type, it is displayed in IE9 Standards mode.
  </p>

</body>
```

So your JS should only be added after the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

is declared.

If your webpage does not include a !DOCTYPE directive or if it specifies a non-standards mode document type, Internet Explorer displays your webpage in IE5 (Quirks) mode. When this happens, Internet Explorer ignores features in your webpage that require standards mode.

REF : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699338(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, The HTML5 doctype is in the markup. Whats really bizarre is that some ie9/10 browsers seem to run fine others are reverting to an ie7 compat view.

Comment: This could be due to local intranet settings on your browser.. 

AFAIK there should be some options in your IE Settings as default "Run intranet in compatibility mode". I'm not sure if this is applicable to you though..

Comment: I know i think my institution is running different zones for different users - this is why my windows test box runs ok and others default to ie7! I have resorted to grabbing the html I need and writing it out using ie conditional tests, not a great fix but will have to do. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: I have accepted answer as in a normal world it would be correct!

Comment: Have you tried IE Conditional tags to see if they are getting mixed up also ? 
If they are not, another (slightly painfull) way would be to add conditional IE mode tags and write up a css sheet for IE Quirks // IE 7 Compat mode ... :| IE Really is the devils work! :D